# Count various types of sequence of values in a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following kind of user journey data which has activity recorded for each user for each time frame on what advertisement he saw or clicked and if 'conversion' happened (which means he brought the product).

A user journey path is defined as the path he took (different type of ads viewed or clicked) in order for him to reach a conversion.

So easy way to look at it would be from time 1 of each user id to trace his path:
p.s. ad_id is a unique identifier for a type of ad. In case of conversion, the ad_id is -1.

| user id | time | activity | ad_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Conversion | -1 |
| 1 | 2 | Click | 101 |
| 1 | 1 | View | 201 |
| 2 | 4 | Conversion | -1 |
| 2 | 3 | View | 101 |
| 2 | 2 | Conversion | -1 |
| 2 | 1 | Click | 101 |
| 3 | 8 | Conversion | -1 |
| 3 | 7 | View | 101 |
| 3 | 6 | Conversion | -1 |
| 3 | 5 | View | 301 |
| 3 | 4 | Conversion | -1 |
| 3 | 3 | CLICK | 201 |
| 3 | 2 | View | 201 |
| 3 | 1 | View | 101 |

So, in this user '1' has the following journey paths in terms of Ad_id (we do not need the detail of his activity leading to the conversion or the time, just the path):

```
201 -> 101 -> -1
```

For user 2, he has the following paths (2 different paths):

```
101 -> -1, 

101 -> -1
```

For user 3 (3 different paths):

```
101 -> -1

101 -> 201 -> 201 -> -1,

301 -> -1
```

The output I desire is to get a count of each kind of path which led to conversion and something like this:

| path | time |
| --- | --- |
| (201,101) | 1 |
| (101) | 3 |
| (101,201,201) | 1 |
| (301) | 1 |

In this, the path needs to be ORDERED from start reaching to the last stage (the -1 being omitted here) so [101,201,201] translates to 101 -> 201 -> 201 -> Conversion

Path [101] has 3 count as this path is coming twice in user id 2 and once in user id 3.

Had this been in python, it would have been a bit easy to do with different paths being different lists and a counter dictionary but I have no clue how can I get this kind of sequence counter output in SQL hence I could not try anything to show my effort. Apologies for that.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(ad_id = -1) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY time DESC) grp
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ad_id ORDER BY time) path
  FROM cte1
  WHERE ad_id <> -1
  GROUP BY userid, grp
  )
SELECT path, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM cte2
GROUP BY path;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/dZ7NosC1

Comment: A really good solution. Thanks! I am thinking but wondering if there's scope for any optimization here